# Reuse class based component to dispatch different action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have class based component connected to redux. I am dispatching an action (updateDownloadCount) from this component. The component renders some ui, has internal state and some functions as well.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateDownloadCount: (id) => {
      ...
    }
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Now i want to reuse this component somewhere else. Everything should stay same except the action. I want to dispatch different action (updateUploadCount).

I can pass some other prop to distinguish and then send different action but that doesn't seems to scale well. Is there any other way i can reuse the component.

Comment: Why doesn't it scale well? This is the entire purpose of [`ownProps` being a parameter](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#arguments) in `mapDispatchToProps`. Definitely be cautious about reusing components when you don't feel like they should be reused, though. You may be tightly coupling things. One smell I use is if you're passing a prop that begins with `is` then you're probably telling your component too much about what it should know rather than how it should behave

Answer (score 1):

You can extract "presentational" part of you component to a separate file and then use it multiple times.

For example

```
// MyComponentUI.js
class MyComponentUI extends Component {
  ...
  // use this.props.updateCount (notice more generic name)
}

export default MyComponentUI
```

**Usage**

```
// UploadComponent.js
import MyComponentUI from "components/MyComponentUI.js"

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateCount: (id) => {
       // dispatch updateUploadCount
    }
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponentUI)
```

and

```
// DownloadComponent.js
import MyComponentUI from "components/MyComponentUI.js"

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    updateCount: (id) => {
       // dispatch updateDownloadCount
    }
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponentUI)
```

Having this approach you can even use your presentational component outside of Redux provider. For example in a storybook or tests.